# SQL delete from query matching condition in two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

All rows are getting deleted with this query while  I only want to delete those rows where `measureid` match in the two tables as below:

```
delete from temp1 
where exists (select t1.* 
              from temp1 t1, temp2 t2 
              where t2.measureid = t1.measureid)
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 3):

i don't think you want to be using `exists` i think you want to use `in`

```
delete from temp1 where measureid in 
    (select t1.measureid from temp1 t1, temp2 t2 where t2.measureid = t1.measureid);
```

or better yet

```
delete from temp1 where measureid in 
    (select measureid from temp2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
select t1.* from temp1 t1, temp2 t2 where t2.measureid = t1.measureid
```

always returns rows. What you probably wanted was

```
delete from temp1 t1 where exists (select t2.* from temp2 t2 where t2.measureid = t1.measureid)
```